# Return HTML from react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new in reactJs
I want to return a HTML code from a function

```
changeValue= (e) =>{
    if(e.target.value=="Albania"){
        return(
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
}

render (){

        return(

               <select onChange= {this.changeValue}>
                   {country}
               </select>


        )
    }
}
```

when I change the select option to Albania the options 1,2 don't show

thank you.

Comment: I think you need to study html first. You need to render options in the beginning

Comment: i mean when i change the value the event changeValue should work and return the selection but it didn't show the selection i don't know why

Comment: and I mean you need to render options first. So user has something to pick on the screen. let me post an answer

Comment: yes i have a selection option which contain all countries name and i put an event onChange the selection value to Albania should the function show the options 1,2

Comment: hmm ok, you need to clarify what you are tying to achieve here?

Comment: i'm trying to know how to show the selection option 1,2

Comment: do you want the show the selection with 1 and 2 to be separate from the countries? Or would you like them to be added to the list of the countries? Or maybe the countries should disappear and only 1 and 2 should be left?

Comment: I want to show the selection with 1,2 in the screen when user select Albania

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to a variable and render it like `{country}` something like below;

```
const selectOption1_2 =null;
changeValue= (e) =>{
    if(e.target.value=="Albania"){
        selectOption1_2 = (
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
    else
        selectOption1_2 = null;

}

render (){

        return(

               <select onChange= {this.changeValue}>
                   {country}
               </select>
               {selectOption1_2}


        )
    }
}
```

it is better to put `selectOption1_2` in state tho.

Comment: i want to show the options 1,2 after the user select Albania in the screen not in the console

Comment: this won't work, because the component won't rerender. You should store selectOption1_2 in state

Comment: @AdamJeliński that is what I suggested at the end of my answer. But I couldn't add state since OP didnt share the whole component. Thank you for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use State for that.

```html
constructor() {
    this.state = {options: countries};  
}

changeValue = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    if(e.target.value=="Albania"){
        this.setState({options: <><option>1</option><option>2</option></>});
    }
}

render () {
    return (
         <select onChange= {this.changeValue}>
             {this.state.options}
         </select>
    )
}
```